# Google Cloud Secrets Manager- Is is possible to use JSON file that contains a lot of key/values and retrieve these credentials from yaml like CredHub

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

Credhubs has a feature where you can upload json file (that contains multiple keys and values) and in the spring boot configs, we can retrieve the specific key value as a variable in the configs.

Is this possible to do something similar in Google Secrets Manager. Like upload JSON file and retrieve from our configs (${sm://keyoftheJsonfile.specifckey.value) )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're able to write Java, you could write your own client - where a `Secret` can have several keys. But these need to be passed into the YAML; guess there is no such shortcut URI, but only REST URL.
https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java